# Pass location reload function as a parameter to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want pass location reload function as a parameter to run function, and run that in run function. In func function case no problem, but in reload function throw exception Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.

How can do this?

```
var func = function(){
    alert(10);
}

var run = function(callback){
    alert(0);
    callback();
    alert(1);
}

run(func);

run(location.reload);
```

Comment: use `location.reload.bind(location)`

Comment: Another solution `run(() => location.reload())`

Comment: @alex: Thanks, its worked

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ehz767zp/

Comment: @jonzee: Thanks, its worked

Comment: other option `run(function(){location.reload();});`

Comment: `run(Function.prototype.bind.call(history.go, history));`